# Find the sides of a right triangle given the area and perimeter

Tags: triangles

I was sure that
this has been asked before,
but the title did not match.

So if the area
of a right triangle is A
and the perimeter is P,
express the sides
a and b
in terms of A and P.

Comment: You know how to write down equations involving $a,b,A,P$, correct? How far do you get when you do that?

Comment: To be clear, marty, is this intended to be a canonical question where you will post a detailed explanation as an answer later on? If so that could excuse the current form of the question, but as it stands I'm sure you're aware that it seems to be rather lacking in context.

Comment: Well, at least it was answered (the same way I did) before it was closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=a+b+\sqrt{(a+b)^2-4A}=P, {a}{b}=2A$

This leads to $P^2-2P(a+b)=-4A$, hence $a+b=\frac{P^2+4A}{2P}$

So $a$ and $b$ are roots of the quadratic equation $x^2-\frac{P^2+4A}{2P}x+2A=0$